# How would you convert alpha characters to n string to uppercase in C?

Tags: c, string, toupper

This is what I have so far. I'm just trying to understand how to implement this function.

```
char toupper(char s[])
{
  s[50] = "hello";
  int i = 0;
  int len;
  len = strlen(s);

  while(i < len) //converting to upper until the length is reached.
   {
    s[i] = putchar(toupper(s[i]));
    i++;
   }
   return s[i];
}
```

Comment: Pardon? Didn't understand. can you be a bit more specific about what you are asking?

Comment: It isn't a good idea to give your function the same name as a library function.

Comment: Why do you have `s[50] = "hello";` inside the function? That overrides whatever is being passed in to the function

Comment: And also won't work as you're trying to assign a string to an element of the array which may or may not be out of bounds.

Comment: Well the original function was defined in  a different language, and I was trying to convert it to C. @ArunAS I see that I do neet to change the name, but I was trying to keep the same names as I was converting it. I did add an underscore to clarify the function.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that OP wants to convert a string to upper case. Now here somehow OP messed up the assignment part. The code can be boiled down to assigning `uppercase` characters to the string passed.

But here, the code is doing something that compiler complains about. `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'`. Well we are trying to assign an `char*` to a `char` so it complained. The whole code can be simplified though with few thoughts. We will write a module that will convert a string to all uppercase. That's it. Then we will test it with "hello" or some string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
void toupperString(char s[])
{
  size_t len = strlen(s), i = 0;

  while(i < len) 
   {
    s[i] = toupper((unsigned char) s[i]);
    i++;
   }
}

int main(void) {
  char s[100];
  strcpy(s,"hello"); // char s[100]="hello" also works;
  toupperString(s);
  printf("%s\n",s );
  return 0;
}
```

Use of your `putchar` was right. So this will work with added feature that it will now go on printing too. (You decide if it's feature - because simply the use will not be that useful other than printing it - always printing whatever is given to the `toupperString` is not a good idea).

```
void toupperString(char s[])
{
  size_t len = strlen(s), i = 0;

  while(i < len) 
   {
    s[i] = toupper((unsigned char) putchar(s[i]));
    i++;
   }
}
```

You have some suspicious use in the function also. For example the return value of it. Why returning the `\0` character? Is it needed? If the answer is no then just make it `void` return type denoting you are not returning anything. Also as array decays into pointer the char array will be changed and you don't need to do anything to return it. As you are basically modifying the original array of characters.

Well we can write it more concisely like this as

```
char* toupperString(char *s)
{
    char *p = s;
    while( *s) 
    {
        *s= toupper((unsigned char) *s);
        ++s;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: @chux.: Rgarding this idea..it was remined to me by Bob__ and then added it.

Answer (score 1):

Your current function has the basic premise of what you're trying to achieve already, but suffers from a number of problems.

Firstly, calling it `toupper` is no doubt giving you headaches because you're implementing the function using the pre-existing `toupper` function. Your function needs to take a string and then return the modified string, but the existing `toupper` is for taking and return a single `char`. Notionally, since you're modifying the passed in string, you don't need to return anything, but it can't hurt to return it.

Secondly you're calling `putchar` for no readily apparent reason. You can leave that out and if required, print the updated string in later parts of your code.

Thirdly, you're returning `s[i]` which is just a `char` and given that `i` has been incremented the length of the string would be pointing at the terminating NUL character.

You also have the spurious line `s[50] = "hello";` which is setting the 51st character of the passed in string to some value, which won't be any of the characters in "hello", but instead will be one of the bytes of the memory location of the string "hello". If you're attempting to declare `s` to be "hello", you should do that in the calling function which I've included as an example.

```
int main(void)
{
  char s[]="hello";
  make_string_upper(s);
  printf("%s\n",s);
}

char *make_string_upper(char *s)
{
  int i = 0;
  int len = strlen(s);

  while(i < len) //converting to upper until the length is reached.
   {
    s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    i++;
   }
   return s;
}
```

Comment: You have already said all what I'd like to comment about OP's code, but may I suggest you to get rid of the call to `strlen`? I think it's useless: https://ideone.com/5IlRo9

Comment: @Bob__ can't not use `strlen` since the function is returning the string.

Comment: @ChrisTurner.: Yikes sorry Chris...Misinterpeted

Comment: @coderredoc your version of the function doesn't return `s` so could be implemented without `strlen` though

Comment: https://ideone.com/cEmO1d, plus in this state your code can invoke UB if strlen return >  `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @ChrisTurner.:Exactly my point..thats why I am doing it. Taking time as I was intiially editing yours.

Comment: I can't say to understand your objection... Do you mind elaborate? Please note that I'm not trying to force you to my point of view.

Comment: If you are using `strlen` then you can ofc avoid the `strlen` because strlen works when the char array is nulll  terminated

Comment: @Bob__ I meant you can't avoid it using the design you supplied...obviously you can if you use another `char *` as per Stargateur's suggestion

Comment: Using `strlen` isn't "useless" - it's just inefficient as you'll end up traversing the string twice. But the basic logic is still sound and it's what the OP provided.

Comment: @Stargateur Sure, but I think they'd be experiencing lots of other issues trying to deal with a 2GB+ string :)